# Does $\int_0^\infty \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x} \text{d}x$ exist if $\phi \in C_0^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Good day,

In the lectures on distribution theory we had a distribution $f \in \mathscr{D}'$ (the dual space of $\mathscr{D}:=C_0^\infty$) defined as 
$$f(\phi):=\langle f,\phi \rangle := \int_0^\infty \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x} \text{d}x$$
for all $\phi \in \mathscr{D}$ and it was stated that linearity and continuity can be proved easily...

But do I even know that the integral exists?

We proved that $$\psi(x):= \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x} \in C^\infty. $$ Additionally we know that $\phi \in \mathscr{D}$ has compact support, so let $\phi$ be an arbitrary test function with  $\text{supp} (\phi) \subset [-M,M], ~M>0$. So I thought I can write

$$\langle f,\phi \rangle := \int_0^\infty \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x} \text{d}x"="\int_0^M \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x} \text{d}x - \int_M^\infty \frac{\phi(0)}{x} \text{d}x $$
but the right integral is clearly infinite if $0 \in \text{supp}(\phi)$, so I am quite irritated how to prove that the integral exists.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot, Marvin

Comment: Maybe the upper bound in the integral was meant to be a finite number, and only by mistake written $\infty$?

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you for your comment. Yeah I also thought of that. One could even save it since this was related to the Cauchy principal value where $$f(\phi)=\lim_{a \to 0} \left(\int_a^\infty \frac{\phi(x)}{x} + \int_{-\infty}^{-a} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \right)$$ and if I set in this first step that $\text{supp} (\phi) \in [-M,M]$ then I get eventually
$$f(\phi)=\int_{-M}^M \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}$$ 
so there really is a finite number as the upper bound. But I wasn't sure if is okay if $f$ is dependent of the support of the test function since in the lecture we wrote it as $\int_0^\infty$.

Comment: @Did $$C_0^\infty = \{ \phi \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) ~|~ \text{supp}(\phi) ~\text{is compact} \} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the integral does not exist if $\phi(0) \ne 0$. Hence, either you have an error in your transcription or the error was present in the lecture.

What could be meant? First, the integral could be $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ (to be understood in a Cauchy-PV sense), or $\int_0^M$ for some fixed $M> 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if it is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}$$ then I have to interpret in a Cauchy-PV sense? Since otherwise there would be same problem in infinity because of $\frac{1}{x}$, I think.
How do I make clear that this special interpretation is meant? Like writing a $PV$ before the integral?

Comment: I think so, because $1/x$ is "not integrable towards infinity". Yes, I think a PV in front of the integral is quite usual.